# Best practice to load multiple DataTable schema from a database into a DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, dataadapter

I'm working in an application dealing with a database having a very dynamic schema. I want to add my database tables schema into a DataSet so that I can get easily my tables column's, type of columns and constraints. I made that possible using the `DataAdapter.FillSchema` method like this way :

```
foreach (string table in get_tables())
        {
            DbDataAdapter myDataAdapter= new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From "+table, myConnexionString);
            myDataAdapter.FillSchema(myDataSet, SchemaType.Source, table);
        }
```

where `get_tables` is a method returning a `List<string>` of my DataBase tables names. This is working perfectly in my case, but i'm not sure if it's the best way to do it? Is there any alternatives ?

Comment: this is a good way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

ADO.Net Connection object has a method called `GetSchema`, which you can use to get the database schema for different objects

```
string[] restrictions = new string[1];
restrictions[0] = "myTableName";
DataTable table = sqlconnection.GetSchema("Tables",restrictions);
```

You can see the details in MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: For the second parameter of the method, restriction should be placed in an array of 4 strings, and the table_name restriction should be placed on the 3rd position not the first according to msdn official doc. Anyway this method works fine too, but I prefer first one because it matches the table schema with the DataTable object with no need to load any data in the rows, although using Connection.GetSchema i have to iterate rows to get database metadata.